# tmap raster layer not rendering pixels full size

Tags: r, tmap

I'm trying to produce a basic heatmap and the grid pixels are rendering very small.

```
require(tmap)
require(dplyr)
require(stars)

d = data.frame(lon = rnorm(1e5, mean = -95.5, sd=4),
               lat = rnorm(1e5, mean = 37.5, sd=4)) |> 
  group_by(lat = round(lat), lon = round(lon)) |> 
  summarise(n = length(lat), .groups = 'drop') |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lon','lat'), crs = 'WGS84') |>
  st_rasterize()

tmap_mode("view")

tm_basemap("Stamen.TonerLite") +
  tm_shape(d) +
  tm_raster("n", palette = c('white','red'), alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

[image]

Grateful for any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Hi @geotheory. Your code works fine on my computer. You may need to update one of the libraries. FYI, I use `tmap 3.3.2` and stars`0.5.5`. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah I'm running those versions

Comment: O.K. thanks for you feedback and glad to know that it now works for you too. Cheers.

Comment: After your last comment, I re-run your script and encountered your problem! But I think I found a workaround (although, to be very honest, I don't really understand this random behavior...). In fact, I think you should set the seed because I was able to reproduce both cases consistently: `set.seed(42)` is O.K.; and with `set.seed(54)` I reproduce the same problem as you (i.e. small pixels).

Comment: Well done for making reproducible. I'm not going mad. Kudos for 42

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241769/discussion-between-geotheory-and-lovalery).

Comment: Posted as an issue in github https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/509